# Apresentar parâmetros de XML em PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

Estou criando uma rotina de leitura de arquivos XML em um diretório, mas estou com dificuldades em conseguir apresentar os elementos do XML. O arquivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://MedicalRecords" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="MedicalRecords http://bns01/ReportServer?%2FBITQNS%2FMedicalRecords&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rs%3ASessionID=fco3lo45kmjbg155n4snltrq&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="MedicalRecords">
   <PacienteSinaisVitais>
      <Report Name="PersonVitalSignsSummary">
         <Tablix4>
            <Details4_Collection>
               <Details4 EventDate4="2019-10-30T18:15:25.393" Peso="82.00" BloodPressureDiastolic2="182.00" BloodPressureStatus2="2.04" IMC="24.80" />
               <Details4 EventDate4="2019-10-17T11:08:57.03" Peso="81.00" BloodPressureDiastolic2="182.00" BloodPressureStatus2="2.02" IMC="24.50" />
            </Details4_Collection>
         </Tablix4>
         <Tablix2 />
         <Tablix3>
            <Details3_Collection>
               <Details3 EventDate3="2019-10-17T11:08:57.03" CardioFreq="76" />
            </Details3_Collection>
         </Tablix3>
         <Tablix5 />
         <Tablix7>
            <Details6_Collection>
               <Details6 EventDate7="2019-10-17T11:08:57.03" CardioFreq4="97" />
            </Details6_Collection>
         </Tablix7>
         <Tablix6 />
      </Report>
   </PacienteSinaisVitais>
   <PacienteEventos>
      <table1_section_Collection>
         <table1_section section="SOAP">
            <Detail_Collection>
               <Detail grupo="Subjetivo" itemDescription="ASSINTOMÁTICO" />
               <Detail grupo="Objetivo" itemDescription="recuperação medular ok&#xA;&#xA;" />
               <Detail grupo="Avaliação" itemDescription="LINFOMA FOLICULAR EC - IV-BS&#xA;1º R-CHOP - 24/10/19" />
               <Detail grupo="Plano" itemDescription="liberado SEGUNDO CICLO DE QT PARA 13/11/19 - 2º  R-CHOP - JÁ AGENDADO NO HNSG&#xA;" />
               <Detail grupo="Observações" />
            </Detail_Collection>
         </table1_section>
         <table1_section section="PEDIDOS PARA RECEPÇÃO">
            <Detail_Collection>
               <Detail grupo="Solicitação" itemDescription="RETORNO - 3 semanas: Consulta marcada para 03/12/2019 10:00" />
               <Detail grupo="Solicitação" itemDescription="LIBERAÇÃO GUIAS: checar agendamento QT 13/11 = hnsg: ok" />
            </Detail_Collection>
         </table1_section>
         <table1_section section="ORDEM DE SERVIÇO">
            <Detail_Collection>
               <Detail grupo="Emissão" itemDescription="Ordem de Serviço para 13/11/2019" />
               <Detail grupo="Emissão" itemDescription="Ordem de Serviço para 14/11/2019" />
               <Detail grupo="Emissão" itemDescription="Ordem de Serviço para 15/11/2019" />
               <Detail grupo="Emissão" itemDescription="Ordem de Serviço para 16/11/2019" />
               <Detail grupo="Emissão" itemDescription="Ordem de Serviço para 17/11/2019" />
            </Detail_Collection>
         </table1_section>
      </table1_section_Collection>
   </PacienteEventos>
</Report>
```

Por exemplo, quero apresentar o valor PESO no index.php:

```
<?php

$dir = "xml/";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      if (($file !== '.') && ($file !== '..') ) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($dir . $file);
        echo $xml->PacienteSinaisVitais->Report->Tablix4->Details4_Collection->Details4->Peso . "<br>";
    }
  }
  closedir($dh);
  }
}

?>
```

Nenhum valor é apresentado na página (fica em branco). Qual a maneira correta de referenciar a variável para apresentar no ECHO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usa o php assim

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("arquivo.xml");
    print_r($xml);
?>
```

ou se o seu xml esta em string dentro de uma variavel

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_string($xml_em_string) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    print_r($xml);
?>
```

Desta forma seu xml sera convertido em um array e basta vc trabalhar a informação que quer como variável independente.

para exibir o peso

```
echo $xml->PacienteSinaisVitais->Report->Tablix4->Details4_Collection->Details4['Peso'];
```

Comment: E como eu apresento só a variável "peso" por exemplo que está dentro de PacienteSinaisVitais? Já que o echo $xml->PacienteSinaisVitais->Report->Tablix4->Details4_Collection->Details4->Peso não funcionou

Comment: me da uns min vou rodar aqui e te dou o ex funcionando